# Laravel Search Relations whereHas

Tags: laravel, search

I am trying to do a search on products but it does not return any results. I suspect it has something to do with the whereHas function but I just cannot figure it out. Here is my code:

My Relations:

Categories Model:

```
class Categories extends Eloquent {

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Products')->orderBy('name');
    }
}
```

Products Model:

```
class Products extends Eloquent {

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category')->orderBy('name');
    }
}
```

My search function:

```
public function search()
{
    $search         = Input::get('search');

    $result             = Products::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%')->get();

    if ($result->first()) {

        return View::make('groceries.index')
        ->with('categories', Categories::with('product')->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->whereHas('product', function($query) use ($search)
        {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
        }));
    }
}
```

In the view:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)

//do stuff

    @foreach ($category->product as $products)

//Show results

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `get()` to get the data.
And I think this will be more readable code.

```
public function search()
{
    $search         = Input::get('search');
    $result         = Products::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%')->get();

    if ($result->first()) {
        $categories = Categories::with('product')->orderBy('name', 'asc')
                                 ->whereHas('product', function($query) use ($search){
                                        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
                                  })->get();
        return View::make('groceries.index')
                   ->with('categories', $categories);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot the get() indeed... :) Awesome!